SwiftUI WheelPickerStyle() in View with viewModel
In this View, clicking the Button while the Picker is spinning, not set on new value, causes the Picker to reset to selectedNumber.  If line Text("(isOn)") is commented out, this does not happen.
I understand that this is due to the view needing to be re-rendered if @State property changes, but why is Picker affected by isOn if it doesn't depend on it?

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedNumber: Int = 0
    @State var isOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonView(isOn: $isOn)
            
            Text("\(isOn)")      // comment this out to stop wheel picker from resetting  

            Picker("Number", selection: $selectedNumber) {
                ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                    Text(String(number)).tag(number)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(isOn ? "OFF" : "ON") {
            isOn.toggle()
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

This is a simple example.  In more complex scenario that I'm working through, View's viewModel has a number of observed properties which are causing the picker to be reset.  One solution here on SO (Weird behaviour of SwiftUI Picker View when the other view getting new value from AVCaptureDevice API) is to eliminate ObservedObjects from the ParentView, moving them to ChildView(s), leaving ParentView which contains the Picker without any ObservedObjects.  This could be very challenging & tedious.  Is there an approach which only requires changes to the Picker?


I understand that this is due to the view needing to be re-rendered if @State property changes, but why is Picker affected by isOn if it doesn't depend on it?

Your understanding is correct. When you press the button, isOn changes and causes a view update of ContentView. This means that ContentView.body is called and everything in the body is updated, including the currently-spinning Picker.
Without Text("\(isOn)"), ContentView.body is not called when you press the button, because nothing in body depends on isOn.
A simple fix is to just move the Picker out of ContentView.body. Put it in a separate view's body.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedNumber: Int = 0
    @State var isOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonView(isOn: $isOn)
            Text("\(isOn)")

            MyPicker(selectedNumber: $selectedNumber)
        }
    }
}

struct MyPicker: View {
    @Binding var selectedNumber: Int
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Number", selection: $selectedNumber) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                Text(String(number)).tag(number)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    }
}

Here, when isOn changes, ContentView.body is called just like before, but MyPicker.body is not called because SwiftUI sees that MyPicker does not depend on isOn (it only depends on selectedNumber). Therefore, the Picker is not updated, and not reset.
In general, you should break down your views into as many small pieces as you can, and as small as you can. By doing this, you limit the scope of influence of @State changes, so that views are not unnecessarily updated. It is through these View structs that SwiftUI figures out the dependencies between things. If you just put everything into a single body, when something changes, that entire thing is updated.

Good advice, after lots of refactoring seeing good results.
